# How to reorder singleTask activity without creating new one?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest, launchmode

I have 2 activity (Activity A and Activity B)

Activity A is singleTask and Activity B has standard launch mode.

When application started with Activity A and launch mode is singleTask, now from activity A start new activity B on button click.

**So Stack is Activity A, B**

Now wanted to reorder Activity A which is single task from Activity B but it's finishing Activity B first and then create new Activity A.

**So stack at the momemnt is only Activity A.**

What I've tried from Activity B.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
startActivity(intent)
```

**Problem**: Without finishing Activity B required to reorder Activity A with launch mode singleTask.

Appreciated in advance.

Comment: Your use of `singleTask` launch mode is causing more problems than it solves. Explain why you need to use `singleTask` launch mode. This special launch mode is usually a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reorder an `Activity` with `singleTask` launch mode to the front of the stack. An `Activity`with `singleTask` launch mode is **by definition** the root `Activity` in a task.

Why would you want to do this? If you've configured the `Activity` as `singleTask`, you have told Android that you want this `Activity` to be launched as the root of a task. Why would you want to reorder this `Activity` to the front of the task? If the `Activity` can exist in the task somewhere other than the root, you shouldn't define it as `singleTask`!